# finding corresopnding origin points based on orientation in iPad

Tags: objective-c

I am working on an iPad app, and it supports four orientations. 
assuming in this app I have one image, that has its origin point at (20, 20) in landscape, is there a mathematical formula to find out its corresponding origin if the app was rotated to portrait?

I can hardcode all possible origin points for the origin point, but that would be a hack, I am looking for a simple formula to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean positioning relative to the screen percentage-wise it would look something like this (pseudo code):

```
widthRelationship= oldScreenWidth/x; // x = horizontal position
heightRelationship= oldScreenHeight/y; // y = vertical position
newX = newScreenWidth/widthRelationship;
newY = newScreenHeight/heightRelationship;
```

The above does not take the size of the image into consideration, only the actual origin point. So, even if the percentage-math is right it might not deliver the visual result you were expecting.

If you are using UIKit there are most likely a lot better ways to achieve the result you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "corresponding origin." I doubt you meant this, but If you mean that you want your views to maintain the same space between them and their superview's edges you can set the `autoresizingMask`. For example, the following effects and masks.

```
//Same spacing relative to the lower left corner
myImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
//Same spacing relative to the upper left corner
myImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
//Same spacing relative to the lower right corner
myImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
//Same spacing relative to the upper right corner
myImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

If you want the view to stay relative percentage wise to *all* edges, then this will do.

```
    myImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

So, for example, if the object is at {20,20} and the screen was {320,480} the new origin for {480,320} after rotation would be roughly {30,13}.